# Download file with DownloadManager on API Level 9+ and fall back to AsyncTask <9

Tags: android, http, download, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-download-manager

I have a service class which should handle downloading of a particular file.

A first version was written using AsyncTask. Since it's a large file and over HTTPS it would be great to use DownloadManager, so I've refactored the service to use the DownloadManager service.

How can I build a service class myself which uses DownloadManager when supported (API-Level >9) and falls back to the AsyncTask-solution when <9?

Comment: I would seriously consider whether it is worth while at all, coding for <= API Level 8. The number of users is now almost literally [non-existant](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). 0.7% of the market share.

Comment: Google Play Services even support API Level 9+. I would also recommend you not to do it.

Comment: Thanks but we have to support <9 with this project, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, here's what I did:

1. Build an abstract service base class e.g. `DownloadService`
2. Extend to concrete subclasses e.g. `AsyncTaskDownloadService` and `DownloadManagerDownloadService`
3. When creating the service, use feature-detection instead of build levels (it's more elegant to me) this looks like the following:

   ```
   Activity activity = getActivity();
   Object downloadService = activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
   Class serviceClass = AsyncTaskDownloadService.class;
   if (downloadService != null) {
       serviceClass = DownloadManagerDownloadService.class;
   }
   Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(activity, serviceClass);
   activity.startService(serviceIntent);
   ```

This will use the older approach when on API level <9 and use the DownloadManager approach when >=9.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I build a service class myself which uses DownloadManager when
>   supported (API-Level >9) and falls back to the AsyncTask-solution when
>   <9?

create your service and check for `build` version if it is greater than 9 run `downloadmanager` else run `asynctask`

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
   //Create your downloadmanager and its request
}else{
    //start using asynctask
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I prefer to use feature detection when possible instead of relying on build versions. It might not be necessary here, but when trying to be future proof it's a good practice.
Also because the different approaches involve a lot of different code I prefer to use two different classes and instantiating the right one at runtime instead of one class with a lot of different code paths per build version.